# Como converter determinado grupo de colunas para JSON?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Possuo uma tabela com N colunas, porem, gostaria de transformar quase todas em uma única coluna do tipo json, ex:

```
  id,
  json(col2,col3,col4) as dados
```

Olhei a documentação, e encontrei um comando que faz algo parecido porem na tabela toda:

```
  SELECT
        array_to_json(array_agg(tab_1))
  FROM 
        tab_1
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso estar resolvendo isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se estiver utilizando **Postgres 9.3**:

```
SELECT id, row_to_json(
    (SELECT d FROM (SELECT col2, col3, col4) d)
) AS dados FROM tab_1;
```

Exemplo no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/20003/1).

No **Postgres 9.4+** fica mais fácil:

```
SELECT id, json_build_object(
    'Coluna 2', col2, 'Coluna 3', col3, 'Coluna 4', col4
) AS dados FROM tab_1;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!